# JavaFX Populating a TableView on main screen from a Modal Window form

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am trying to populate a TableView from a method call on the click of a button from a Modal Window. I hope this is possible but I am not having any luck. The TableView is already created in an FXML file. Whenever I call upon the method, I receive a null pointer exception. Any ideas, or suggestions? Sorry if my question format is bad, I don't ask many questions.

**MainController.java**

```
@FXML TableView<Part> partsTableView;
@FXML ObservableList<Part> parts;
@FXML public TableColumn<Part, Integer> partIDColumn;
@FXML public TableColumn<Part, String> partNameColumn;
@FXML public TableColumn<Part, Integer> partILColumn;
@FXML public TableColumn<Part, Double> partPriceColumn;

    @FXML
    public void getPartData(){
      partIDColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id")); (Line 112)
      partNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
      partILColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("instock"));
      partPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
      partsTableView.setItems(generateData());
    }

    private ObservableList<Part> generateData(){
      parts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
      parts.add(new Part(0, "Part" , 1 , 25.00));

     return parts;
    }
```

**main.fxml**

```
    <TableView fx:id="partsTableView" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="68.0" prefHeight="344.0" prefWidth="556.0">
      <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="partIDColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="138.0" resizable="false" text="Part ID" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="partNameColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="139.0" resizable="false" text="Part Name" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="partILColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="119.0" resizable="false" text="Inventory Level" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="partPriceColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="159.0" resizable="false" text="Price / Cost Per Unit" />
      </columns>
    </TableView>
```

Error: **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ims.MainController.getPartData(MainController.java:112)**

I am using IntelliJ and I build my stage / scene in Scene Builder. I apologize if this is really simple and I'm overlooking something, but, I am just having such a tough time figuring this out.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

Comment: Without seeing the `Part` class its hard for me to see exactly where an error may occur. One such error could be that there is not `getId()` function that return an `Integer`, but rather it may return an `int`, and it definitely matters. Adjust accordingly of this is correct. All info located on the `PropertyValueFactory` docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html intro paragraphs.

Comment: 1. Post the complete stack trace. 2. Post the code for the controller for the modal window. How are you getting the reference to the main controller into that controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have prepared a sample. You can follow its logic. Main point is to manage main dialog and modal dilog controllers. You can check `DialogController dialogController = fxmlLoader.<DialogController>getController();` line in AppMainController.java. In this sample main controller (`AppMainController`) obtains dialog controller (`DialogController`) and sets its observablelist to dialog controller. Sample class and fxmls are below:

AppMain.java:

```
package populatetable;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AppMain extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AppMain.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500,500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

AppMain.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane minHeight="500.0" minWidth="500.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" fx:controller="populatetable.AppMainController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="tvData" layoutX="91.0" layoutY="159.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="colId" prefWidth="75.0" text="ID" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="colName" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
      <Button layoutX="211.0" layoutY="85.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onOpenDialog" text="Open Dialog" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

AppMainController.java

```
package populatetable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AppMainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Data> tvData;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn colId;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn colName;

    private ObservableList<Data> tvObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    // Open dialog button click event
    @FXML
    void onOpenDialog(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("onOpenDialog clicked");

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Dialog.fxml"));
        Parent parent = fxmlLoader.load();
        DialogController dialogController = fxmlLoader.<DialogController>getController();
        dialogController.setAppMainObservableList(tvObservableList);
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent, 300, 200);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        colId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
        colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        tvData.setItems(tvObservableList);

    }

    public ObservableList<Data> getTvObservableList() {
        return tvObservableList;
    }


}
```

DialogController.java

```
package populatetable;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class DialogController  {


    private ObservableList<Data> appMainObservableList;

    //fill table button click event
    @FXML
    void fillTable(ActionEvent event) {

        Data data = new Data(1, "Name1");
        appMainObservableList.add(data);

    }

    public void setAppMainObservableList(ObservableList<Data> tvObservableList) {
        this.appMainObservableList = tvObservableList;

    }

}
```

Dialog.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane minHeight="200.0" minWidth="300.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" fx:controller="populatetable.DialogController">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="115.0" layoutY="89.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#fillTable" text="Fill Table" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Data.java

```
package populatetable;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Data {

    private final SimpleIntegerProperty id;
    private final SimpleStringProperty name;


    public Data(int id, String name) {
        this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setId(int ID) {
        id.set(ID);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String nme) {
        name.set(nme);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id: " + id.get() + " - " + "name: " + name.get();
    }

}
```

Hope it is useful.

Comment: Thank you! This is VERY helpful. You are very much appreciated. I see what I was doing wrong and should be able to continue with my project!!